# VB6 to .Net 4.0 Conversion 3rd party tools

Tags: .net, visual-basic-6

Since Visual Studio 2010 does not come with a VB6 conversion tool, the boss wants to use a 3rd party tool (i.e VBUC) that Microsoft is suggesting.

Has anyone used one of these 3rd party tools/services?

If so, have you found them to be worth the money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeArchitects.

Used on our current project before I came along.

Not *entirely* unreasonable, but:  starting in VB6 is unreasonable.  You can only climb so far out of that hole.  Sadly. :(

http://www.vbmigration.com/Default.aspx

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly at this point, there is so much to take advantage of in the .Net 4 (vb) language and the paradigm shift is so significant, that I can't imagine taking my older VB 6 projects and trying some sort of straight conversion. The conclusion can only be some sort of raw kludge that you'll end up redesigning anyway.

Most of my VB6 projects are 1/2 the lines of code in .Net upgrades. Plus, there are third party tools (DevExpress / Telerik come to mind) which can take any stuff that used to take you 100+ hours to develop in VB 6 and make it a few line piece of cake.

Unless you're simply extremely strapped for time, take the plunge - you won't be sorry.

Comment: agreed...  however, this isn't my decision...